# Uknown TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable and I have now clue what this means. I'm currently following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNa99PG8hR8

for learing how to create a simple machine learning program using a data table provided by wikepedia which shows 3 types of tulips and the program is supposed to distinguish one from another. Right now though, it is only supposed to print the expected results for the 3 tulip types at 0, 50 and 100.

I tried to redownload python (I'm using linux) but it didn't solve the problem.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

iris = load_iris()
test_idx = [0, 50, 100]

# training data
train_target = np.delete(iris.target, test_idx)
train_data = np.delete(iris.data, test_idx, axis=0)

# testing data
test_target = iris.target[test_idx]
test_data = iris.data[test_idx]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(train_data, train_target())

print test_target
```

The program is supposed to display the target data display of the training data that will be used for testing after the model has completed it's training

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

means that you use the `()`operator on an object that does not implement it (in this case a numpy.ndarray).

A simple example would be trying to do the following:

```
int i = 0;
print(i())
```

This does not work as `int` does not implement the `()` operator and is therefor not callable.

To fix your error:

The line (as @Oswald said):

```
clf.fit(train_data, train_target())
```

should look like this:

```
clf.fit(train_data, train_target)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It fixed the problem!

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `()` from `train_target` in `clf.fit`, adding round braces will make it a callable